# Question about group algebras and representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Hello I am currently learning about group algebras and representations. And our professor gave us in the corona-online semester only handwritten notes and thats all..

And there was one topic I am kind of stuck on..

**(1)**

If we have a semisimple Module $A_A=S_1^{n_1}\oplus ... \oplus S_l^{n_l}$ with $S_i$ beeing simple Modules over an

$\mathbb{C}-$Algebra $A$ then we can split $A$ into:

$$A\cong M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C})\oplus...\oplus M_{n_l}(\mathbb{C})$$

**How** do the Elements of $M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C})\oplus...\oplus M_{n_l}(\mathbb{C})$ **look like? And how can I do calculation with them**

**(2)**

If we now look at one piece of the Algebra $A$ for example $M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C})$, then $M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C})\cong \oplus_{n_1}\mathbb{C}^{n_l}$ which gives that the

simple $A-$modules are $\mathbb{C}^m$ column vectors or something.. here I am already very confused.. what are the simple $A-$Modules ? Are they really just the column vectors?

---

**(3)**

Next question is: Given a group representation $\rho: G \longrightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ what is the "of $\rho$ induced $\mathbb{C}[G]$-Module" my guess was that its $\mathbb{C}^n$ column vectors with $g\mathbb{C}^n:= \rho(g)\mathbb{C}^n$

Sorry for the maybe out of context questions, and if any question doesnt even make sense..

Comment: Just a comment about the notation. It seems that $M_{n_i}(\Bbb C)$ denotes the set of $n_i\times n_i$ matrices over $\Bbb C$, and the $\oplus$ symbol would be a direct sum of matrices. That is, you have a matrix with diagonal blocks $A_1,\ldots,A_l$ where $A_i$ is a $n_i\times n_i$ complex matrix.

Comment: ohh this is a first big help

Comment: This means, my Algebra $A$ looks like a special kind of $\sum_i n_i \times \sum_i n_i $ matrix?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I'd like to say yes but I am also kind of confused with how the isomorphism is obtained. So sorry and hope more experts from this community can answer your question.